# How to use cookie from response in a request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a login token in my response sent from the API :

```js
const loginUser=asynchandler(
    async(req,res)=>{
        const {username,password}=req.body
        if(!username||!password)return res.status(400).json({'message':'required!'})

        const user=await User.findOne({name:username})
        if(!user){
            res.status(404).json({'message':'User not found.'})
        }
        else{

            const checkpass=await bc.compare(password,user.pass)
            if(checkpass){
                const payload={
                    name:user.name,
                }
                const token=generateToken(payload);
                
                res.status(200).cookie('token',token).json('ok')              
            }
            else res.status(400).json({'message':'wrong password'})
        }
    }
)
```

LoginPage.js(client-side)

```
export default function Login(){
    const [username,setusername]=useState('')
    //const [resusername,setresusername]=useState(null)
    const [password,setpassword]=useState('')
    const [redirect,setredirect]=useState(false)
    async function login(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        const response=await fetch('http://localhost:4000/login',{
            method:'POST',
            body:JSON.stringify({username,password}),
            headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
           credentials:'include' 
         })
        try{
            if(response.ok){
                setredirect(true);
            }
        }catch(err){
            alert(err)
        }
    }
        if(redirect){
        return <Navigate to={'/'} />
    }
```

I want to sent that `cookie`  back to the server through a component (Header that checks if a user is logged in and renders user.name and other functionalities)

```
export default  function Header(){
    const [username,setusername]=useState(null)
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/checker',{
            credentials:'include'
        }).then(res=>res.json.then(user=>setusername(user)))
    },[])
    return(
        <nav>
            {username?
            <div>
              <h1>{username}</h1>    
              <Link to={'/logout'}>Logout</Link>   
            </div>
            :
            <>
            <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
            <Link to='/register'>Register</Link>
     
            </> }
       </nav>

    )
}
```

But the request if sending no token to the server therefore I get a JWT error.

```js
const checker=asynchandler(
    async(req,res)=>{
       const {token}=req.cookies;
       if(token){
        console.log(token);
           const payload=jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_SECRET)
           res.status(200).json(payload)
        }else{
            res.status(400).json('token undefined')
        }
       //res.status(200).json({'msg':req.cookies}) 
    }
)
```

How do I get the token from my response (only if it exists) and sent it back to the server for verification.

I tried to save in the `localStorage` then ditched the idea. Anyone know what am I missing here?

Comment: Show how you send login request